# Export to Excel for absolute path

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to export a report to Excel. Using POI I'm able to store in to the path (say D:/reports) which I hardcoded in my code.

My requirement is, before the report generation, to ask for the path, the user wants to save the report to.  How to achieve this?

Comment: store in servlet context path or your container contex path.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it for somewhat more info

Comment: On which server you are going to deploy your project ?

Comment: It's on tomcat Suresh Atta

Comment: You can't store users computer directly. Send it as a response back after the generation of file on server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot store a file in user's computer without his permission/action.

```
1)Store your generated file in container (Tomcat's folder).
2)Write the file as response content.
3) Users get's a prompt to select the location to save the file to disk.
4) Delete the generated file after successfully writing to the user's computer.
```

Comment: How to get that prompt to save ?

Comment: When you try to write a file to response, browser automatically prompt the user. You need not to do anything. Just write the file as content to response.

Comment: try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\excelFormat.xslx"));
            workBook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("excel written successfully");
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Excel";          This is the code I used to report generation @Suresh

Answer (score 0):

you can't store the file in users computer.

Convert your workbook to `byte array` and write the file as response content.

Try the following:

```
// converting workbook to byte array
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] bytes = null;
try {
    workbook.write(outStream);
    bytes = outStream.toByteArray();
} finally {
    outStream.close();
}

 // setting file properties
 response.setContentType('application/vnd.ms-excel');
 response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=excelname.xls");


// writing the byte[] to repsonse.
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(bytes);
out.close();
```

By using the above code, you don't need save the file in tomcat and User gets a prompt to save the file in his location.

Comment: Did you read whole answer or just made an assumption with first words  ???  So are you going to store a file in user's computer with out his permission/action?? Just for say, can you store a file in my machine with your codes ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ your answer?

Comment: Your whole answer is my second part. You just showed the implementation of it. `2)Write the file as response content.`

Comment: And OP never asked for codes. She is missing a point that she can't access users computer. Instead she have to send file as response content, when user click `generate report`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I just gave an example how to the send the excel file to user. My answer looks like your second and third points. In your first point you are saying to create a file in container and fourth point is for deleting the file. These two are not necessary to send excel file to user.

Comment: Killers clue here.. Wait. It seems POI giving a byte stream of report. Then there is no need to create a temp file.